# How do I save the state of a selected checkmark?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-preferences, android-checkbox

I have my code in which, I have 2 checkboxes.When one of them is selected the other is unselected and vice versa. It works fine ,except for the fact that when I click on back button on this fragment ,it somehow saves the state of the last selected checkbox (doesnt update the content as expected which should be done only when I click on done button). Also, when I refersh my page or change my tablet orientation it reverts back to the default page (in this case personal list). I want to have it work such that not only the state of the selected checkbox is saved but also the related fragment content is saved too. Also, on clicking back it shouldn't save anything unless I click on done button. I know it's to be done in sharepreferencesmanager, but I am not sure how to go about it and where to place the calls, does anyone have a clue? Here's my code for the same:

```
public class Listfragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnCheckedChangeListener {
        public final static String TAG_MANAGE_LIST_CATEGORIES_FRAGMENT = "Listfragment";
        private boolean mIsPersonal = true; 
        private boolean mIsShared = true;
        public static final String ANIMATION = "animation";
        private boolean mShouldbeon;
        private boolean mInitialShouldbeon;
        private boolean mShouldbeon1;
        private boolean mInitialShouldbeon1;
        protected Button mPreferencesDoneButton;
        private SharedPreferences sp;
        final boolean isPersonal = true;
        final boolean isShared = true;
        Button sharedbutton;
        Button personalbutton;
        private ListsFragment mListsFragment;
        ToggleButton one; 
        ToggleButton two;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_lists, container, false);
            final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
            final ListActivity activity = (ListActivity) getActivity();


            return view;
        }
        protected void setupClickListeners() {
            mIsPersonal = isPersonal;
            mPreferencesDoneButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_done);
            Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(mPreferencesDoneButton.getContext().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/proxima-nova-regular.ttf");
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setTypeface(face);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(((ListActivity) getActivity()).isDoneButtonEnabled());
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            final TextView titleView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
            titleView.setText(R.string.manage_dashboard_lists);

            initListfragment();

        }

        private void initListfragment() {
            populateData();
            setupClickListeners();
            sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

             personalbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_personal_list);
            personalbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
             sharedbutton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_shared_list);
            sharedbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
            one = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.personal_list_toggle_control);
            one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            Log.d("LISTY", "1");
            boolean toogle = sp.getBoolean("toggle", true);
            two = (ToggleButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.shared_list_toggle_control);
            two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            Log.d("LISTY", "2");

            if(toogle){
                one.setChecked(true);
                Log.d("LISTY", "3");
            }
                else{
                two.setChecked(true);
                Log.d("LISTY", "4");
                }


        }
        protected void populateData() {
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().updateIsUserPreferencesUpdated(false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final ListActivity activity = (ListActivity) getActivity();

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_personal_list:
                    mIsPersonal = true;
                    mIsShared = false;
                    one.setChecked(true);
                    Log.d("LISTY", "5");

                    sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", mIsPersonal).commit();
                   Log.d("listdash", "Personal List is selected in onclick : "+mIsPersonal);

                    return;

                case R.id.button_shared_list:
                    mIsPersonal = false;
                    mIsShared = true;
                    two.setChecked(true);
                    sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", !mIsShared).commit();
                    Log.d("listdash", "Shared List is selected in onclick : "+mIsShared);
                    Log.d("LISTY", "6");
                    return;


                case R.id.button_done:
                    Log.d("LISTY", "7");
                    boolean tabletSize = Utils.isTablet(activity);
                    int layoutType = Application.getAppResources().getInteger(R.integer.layout_type);

                            if(one.isChecked()){
                                DashboardFragment.getInstance().getListsFragment().setIsPersonal(ListsFragment.LIST_TYPE.PERSONAL);
                                Log.d("LISTY", "8");
                            }else{
                                DashboardFragment.getInstance().getListsFragment().setIsPersonal(ListsFragment.LIST_TYPE.SHARED);
                                Log.d("LISTY", "9");

                    }
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }

            activity.onBackPressed();
            Log.d("LISTY", "10");
        }


        protected void toggleDoneButton() {
            boolean isUserPreferencesUpdated = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().isUserPreferencesUpdated();
            Log.d("LISTY", "13");
            boolean isDoneEnabled = (
                     mShouldbeon != mInitialShouldbeon || mShouldbeon1 != mInitialShouldbeon1
                    || isUserPreferencesUpdated);
            mPreferencesDoneButton.setEnabled(isDoneEnabled);
            Log.d("LISTY", "14");

        }

        public void onUpdate() {
            mListsFragment.onUpdate();
            Log.d("LISTY", "15");
        }


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked ){
                 if ( buttonView == one ) {
                        two.setChecked(false);
                        one.setEnabled(false);
                        two.setEnabled(true);
                        Log.d("LISTY", "18");
                        personalbutton.setEnabled(false);
                        sharedbutton.setEnabled(true);
                        sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", true).commit();
                        Log.d("listdash", "Personal List is selected in onchecked : "+mIsPersonal +one +two);

                    }
                 else if (buttonView == two) {
                        one.setChecked(false);
                        two.setEnabled(false);
                        one.setEnabled(true);
                        Log.d("LISTY", "19");
                        personalbutton.setEnabled(true);
                        sharedbutton.setEnabled(false);
                        sp.edit().putBoolean("toggle", false).commit();
                        Log.d("listdash", "Shared List is selected in oncheck : "+mIsShared +one +two);

                    }
                }
            switch (buttonView.getId()) {

                case R.id.personal_list_toggle_control:

                    mShouldbeon = isChecked;
                    Log.d("LISTY", "20");

                    break;
                case R.id.shared_list_toggle_control:

                    mShouldbeon1 = isChecked;
                    Log.d("LISTY", "21");

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            toggleDoneButton();
        }
```

Thanks! P.S: it will be great if you can explain with respect to my code.

Answer (score -1):

You can place your code in onResume, So your app will work as per your need

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...

}
```